# loop in loop creating a vector in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

I would like to create a vector using names and numbers.

I have 2 groups : A and B.
I have 2 genders: male and female
I have 2 animals: dog and cat

Instead of writing a vector containting the name of each group:

```
vector= c("Amaledog","Afemaledog","Amalecat","Afemalecat","Bmaledog","Bfemaledog","Bmalecat","Bfemalecat")
```

I would like to use loop in loop:

```
group=c("A","B")
gender=c("female","male")
animal=c("dog","cat")

for (a in group){
 for (b in gender){
  for (c in animal){
   vector=paste0(a,b,c)
  }
 }
}
```

But I only obtain :
"Bmalecat"

Do you know why? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please mark one of the answers below as correct, if any worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite `vector` each time, that's the problem. What you probably want to do is

```
vect <- character(length(group) * length(gender) * length(animal))

i <- 1
for (a in group){
  for (b in gender){
    for (c in animal){
      vect[i] <- paste0(a,b,c)
      i <- i + 1
    }
  }
}
```

It's important to preallocate the vector in order to avoid a hell lot of (inefficient) reallocation. You should preferably use a vectorised solution.

Comment: I feel like a broken record: "Do not grow an object in a loop. At least pre-allocate to the final size." `vect <- character(length(group) * length(gender) * length(animal))`

Comment: @Roland that's precisely what I told myself

Comment: Thank you Eli Korvigo and Roland for your answers.It will work for me. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(group=c("A","B"),gender=c("female","male"),animal=c("dog","cat"))
```

Output :

```
  group gender animal
1     A female    dog
2     B female    dog
3     A   male    dog
4     B   male    dog
5     A female    cat
6     B female    cat
7     A   male    cat
8     B   male    cat
```

Edit :

```
do.call(paste0, expand.grid(group=c("A","B"),gender=c("female","male"),animal=c("dog","cat")))
```

This should do it, as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: `do.call(paste0, expand.grid(group, gender, animal))`

Comment: thank you for you answer. I want to have one vector containing the names and not a data :)

Comment: Edited the answer, using Roland's advice

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table` with the cross join (`CJ`)

```
library(data.table)
CJ(group, gender, animal)[, do.call(paste0, .SD)]
#[1] "Afemalecat" "Afemaledog" "Amalecat"   "Amaledog"   "Bfemalecat"
#[6] "Bfemaledog" "Bmalecat"   "Bmaledog"
```